# Gummi: Error compiling bibliography file; where's the log?

Tags: bibliographies, compiling, gummi

I'm using bibliography with Gummi, and when I git "Detect" in the "Bibliography" menu it works and shows all my references. However when I hit "Compile" I get "Error compiling bibliography file," without any further explanation. Is there a log sommewhere etc that can tell me what's wrong (This doesn't show up in the regular Build log)?

I use JabRef so my bibliography file is processed through this.

Comment: On my system, `.log` and `.aux` and the like are in `/tmp`

Comment: I do find some files there but not the ones I need I think (no new ones are produced when I try to compile the bibliography)

Comment: You need a `tex` code you can compile. This `tex` code calls the bibliography to be build with `\cite` commands and a bib file.  You will get only a `blg` file if you "compile" the `bib` file with `bibtex` or `biber`.

Comment: Turns out the problem was I was using `includeonly{}`, so the uncompiled files had no .aux etc. I forgot forgot I was using this and hence didn't mention it in the op.

Comment: Closed, the reason was mentioned by the OP in a comment above.

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu), I found log files in `~/.cache/gummi/`